# El resultado no se visualiza en JSF pero sí en consola

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee, java-8

Estoy tratando realizar una visualización de factura en otra pagina y resulta que me sale `null` pero en la consola me aparece el resultado de la factura.

Este es una parte mi código donde hago la consulta de factura en otra pagina. el archivo es `facturaBean.java`:

```
public String outcome() {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.visualizarfact = Integer.parseInt(getNumeroFacturaParam(fc));
    System.out.println("Factura : " + this.visualizarfact);
    return "FacturaShow.jsf";
}

//get value from "f:param"
public String getNumeroFacturaParam(FacesContext fc) {

    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    return params.get("numerofactura");

}
```

En esta parte es la vista donde aparece todo el listado de factura para consultar con diferentes opciones `FacturaIndex.xhtml`, al final del código observará con `commandLink` que estoy llamando al `FacturaShow.xhtml`:

```
                <h:form id="formMostraFacturas">
                <p:dataTable id="tablaFacturas" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" rows="20"
                             var="ft" value="#{facturaBean.listaFacturas}" emptyMessage="No hay datos de Facturas"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                    <p:column headerText="NRO." style="width: 40px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.numeroFactura}" style="display:block;text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="EMPRESA" style="width: 500px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.cliente.nombreCliente}"/>
                    </p:column>                        

                    <p:column headerText="RUC" style="width: 100px" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.cliente.rucCliente}" style="display:block;text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="MONEDA" style="width: 70px" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.moneda.simboloMoneda}" style="display:block;text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="TOTAL" style="width: 100px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{ft.totalVenta+(ft.totalVenta*0.18)}" style="display:block;text-align: right">
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="###,###,##0.00" type="currency"
                                             locale="en_US" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="IMPRIMIR" style="width: 70px; text-align: center">
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura1" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Visualizar Factura PDF" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaNavegadorPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/impresora.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura2" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Descargar Factura en PDF" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaExportadaPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/descargapdf.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura3" target="_blank" actionListener="#{facturaBean.pedirFactura(ft.numeroFactura, ft.totalVenta, ft.moneda.simboloMoneda)}"                                           
                                       title="Imprimir en la impresora Matricial" action="#{facturaBean.verFacturaMatrixNavegadorPDF()}" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/impresoramatricial.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="OPCIONES" style="width: 70px; text-align: center">
                        <p:commandLink id="reportefactura4"
                                       oncomplete="PF('dialogVerFactura').show();"
                                       update=":formVerFactura" >
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{facturaBean.factura}" value="#{ft}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/ojo.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </p:commandLink>
                        <p:outputLabel value=" "/>
                        <p:commandLink id="reportefactura5"
                                       target="_blank" title="Anular Factura" >
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/anular.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </p:commandLink>

                        <h:commandLink id="reportefactura6" action="#{facturaBean.outcome}">
                            <f:param name="numerofactura" value="#{ft.numeroFactura}"/>
                            <h:graphicImage value="/resources/Imagenes/ojo.png" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

Ahi, en esta `FacturaShow.xhtml`, se muestra lo indicado:

```
<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="./../../Plantilla/Plantilla.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <p><h2>Visualizando la Factura</h2></p>
            <h:form>
                <h:outputText value="f1: #{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                <p></p>
                <h:outputText value="f2: #{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                <p></p>
                <h:outputFormat value="Invoice : {1}">
                    <f:param value="#{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                    <f:param value="#{facturaBean.visualizarfact}"/>
                </h:outputFormat>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

Y por ultimo le estoy compartiendo el imagen donde aparece `null`, este es un código simple pero no logro el resultado para poder seguir con Hibernate.

[image: Imagen_Error]

Answer (score 1):

Si el scope de tu bean NO es session, cada vez que ingreses a una nueva página toda la información almacenada se borra. Asumiendo que ese sea tu problema debes de cambiar el scope a @SessionScoped asi:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "facturaBean", eager = true)
@SessionScoped 
public class FacturaBean(){
...
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Mauro, lo resolvi!!! estaba con @ViewScoped. Ahora si ya puedo continuar.  Ahora bien, observo el código que me has indicado @ManagedBean(name="facturaBean", eager=true), pregunto por obligación tengo agregar eager=true, sin eso trabaja bien e incluyendo name="facturaBean", explicame por favor. debo entender eager=true realiza un solicitud , sin eager tendría varias solicitudes.  Saludos,

Comment: Hola, me alegro que te haya servido mi respuesta. Tengo entendido que el eager = true se usa para crear el bean apenas inicies la aplicacioón, si le quitas el eager el bean se crea cuando lo llames, de ti depende borrarlo o no, de acuerdo a tus necesidades, te puedo aclarar que para resolver el problema del scope no es necesario, la verdad lo puse es por que así lo muestran en los ejemplos, yo no uso anotaciones, los beans los configuro desde el faces-config.xml, un saludo.

Comment: @MauroFlorez eager loading se traduze carga temprana, contrario a lazy loading que significa carga tardía.