# Cambiar valor de un selectOneRadio en JSF y PrimeFaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Necesito asignar los valores de un `selectOneRadio`.

Mi intención es que cuando el usuario presiona un botón de editar, este mismo cargue lo que el usuario insertó.

Mi código imprime el resultado deseado en la consola, pero no lo cambia en la vista.

Estoy usando *JSF* y *PrimeFaces*.

Este es el código:

Vista (*JSF*):

```
 <p:selectOneRadio id="selectPosicionGeo" value="#{notificationsBean.positionInGeo}" layout="grid" columns="1" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dentro de geocerca" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fuera de geocerca" itemValue="2" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{notificationsBean.positionUnit()}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

*JavaBean*:

```
if (notificacion != null) {
    if (notificacion.getPosicionInOut() != null) {
        if (notificacion.getPosicionInOut().equals("IN")) {
            this.positionInGeo = "1";
        } else if (notificacion.getPosicionInOut().equals("OUT")) {
            this.positionInGeo = "2";
        }
    }
}
```

No sé exactamente qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal, o por qué en mi vista no se cambia, por último pongo la pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el objeto `positionInGeo` es donde se tiene que asignar los valores que previamente el usuario agregó, el problema es en el apartado *Posición* de la unidad.

Comment: Posiblemente porque no se entera del cambio, en vez de poner directamente this.positionInGeo = "2"; intenta setPositionInGeo("2");

Comment: Hola buenos dias, apenas volví a retomar este tema, y desafortunadamente no funcionó, mis validaciones si están bien, ya que en el debug eso es lo que me trae según sea el valor y el problema es que no cambia de posición del radioButton :(

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [El resultado no se visualiza en JSF pero sí en consola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95069/el-resultado-no-se-visualiza-en-jsf-pero-s%c3%ad-en-consola)